# Category and tags are not working properly

Tags: categories, themes, tags

When click on cateory or tag they diplaying all posts in the every category but every categpry have different posts.Please help how to fix this.

Using Blockkit Corporate Theme

Comment: Have you modified the theme at all? Such as changing the archive templates? If not, you'll probably need to speak to the theme author, as this sounds like a problem with the theme.